# How long would an international wire from US -> UK take?

Tags: international, wire-transfer

I've recently been paid in wire from the US, my bank is HSBC - how long would the transaction usually take?

Thanks!

Comment: US to Germany is 'next business day' (if you submitted early enough). Anything longer for the UK would surprise me.

Comment: @Aganju It was submitted on Wednesday & I haven't received it yet

Comment: Have you called them?

Answer (score 1):

Best case an international transaction can happen same day or within a few hours. Worst case, three weeks or more. If it hasn't come for more than a week I would start calling or emailing both sides of the transaction to get the bank(s) looking to see if the transaction got stuck somewhere.